# Cordova - Is there a plugin which pulls photos from the device library without a picker dialog?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, photo

I'd like to build in a photo/video library browser similar to Facebook Messenger, Instagram, Tumblr. Those apps present a custom photo browser without the built-in OS media library picker dialog. I think I'd need a plugin which gives me API access to query and retrieve media items, for example for ios, with PHImageManager rather than UIImagePickerController.

Anybody know of such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin to get all images in gallery and display in div https://github.com/Whebcraft/cordova-gallery-api